# How to make my shell run in 10 minutes after the pc reboot?

Tags: shell, cron

I can make my shell script run at the startup  with  /etc/init.d/start_app.
I want to make my shell script run in 10 minutes after the pc reboot everytime?
How express my meaning with crontab command?
10 minutes after pc reboot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by

```
@reboot sleep 600 && my_script.sh
```